# Set value in PnP taxonomy picker control on client side

Tags: sharepoint-online, taxonomy

I have 2 PnP Taxonomy picker control in SharePoint online in my page. I initialize these control as below

```
$('#taxPickerKeywords_' + p).taxpicker({
 isMulti: false, 
 allowFillIn: true, 
 useKeywords: true, 
 termSetId: 'GUID'
}, context);
```

Now I need to set the value of second control with first control value. I can get the value from first control but unable to set second control value using `.val()` in jQuery.

After I initialize my taxpicker the HTML looks like below

```
<div class="cam-taxpicker">
  <div class="cam-taxpicker-editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <div class="cam-taxpicker-button"></div>
  <input type="hidden" id="taxPickerKeywords_0">
</div>
<div class="cam-taxpicker-suggestion-container"></div>
```

Any idea or suggestion for setting the value for this control?

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround for this. The value was getting set using `$('#tax_2').val(value);` but it was not appearing in the editor. So I updated its value and then set the editor element as in the first tax picker.

```
//setting the value of 2nd control
$('#tax_2').val(value);

//cloning the elements of 1st control's editor
var clonedVar = $('#tax_1').parent().find('.cam-taxpicker-editor').children().clone();

//emptying the 2nd control's editor if any other value is present
$('#tax_2').parent().find('.cam-taxpicker-editor').empty();

//appending the editor element to 2nd control
$('#tax_2').parent().find('.cam-taxpicker-editor').append(clonedVar);
```

This worked for me as I was copying the value already present in one taxonomy picker. I am also able to read these values and save them to backend. User can even change the value after copy.